# Assert that Set contains object when expected with a partial copy - Jest

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, set, jestjs

I have a set that contains object of structure:

```
{
    param1: string,
    param2: string,
    param3: string
}
```

Would it be possible to perform the `Set.has` check against my set when attempting to match partial copies of the data contained? ie. an object containing:

```
{
    param2: string,
    param3: string
}
```

Where the expected object misses out the first `param1` parameter...

I have attempted the following:

```
expect(mySet.has(expect.objectContaining(myData))).toBeTruthy();
```

I would have thought the `expect.objectContaining()` would have solved my issue...

I have also tried 'enriching' the expected data by adding:

```
myData.param1 = expect.any(String);
```

But this equally did not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into array and assert that each item of the array will only contain objects and describe the objects

```
describe('mySet', () => {
  const items = Array.from(mySet);
  test.each(items)('that each item of your set has objects with the following stucture', item => {
    expect(item).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        param2: expect.any(String),
        param3: expect.any(String)
      })
    )
  });
});
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/WorseAdoredSandbox)